# Copy add or combine a model

Tags: c#, model, copy

I am having problem adding to the model. I want to have a list in the Root1 or in the Viewmodel like fullname and authors list.

newModel1
AuthorsAccepted  count=4
FullName = Jack

AuthorsAccepted  count=4
FullName = Time Dean

With the code below it only adds the last one to the Root1. I created a a third model. Is there  a way I can add to the third model both the lists or in Root1.

```
        var fullName = "Jack";
        var fullName2 = "Tim Dean";

        var authors1 = new List<AuthorsAccepted1>() {
            new AuthorsAccepted1(){ id = 1, Name="Bill"},
            new AuthorsAccepted1(){ id = 2, Name="Steve"},
            new AuthorsAccepted1(){ id = 3, Name="jon"},
            new AuthorsAccepted1(){ id = 4, Name="nick"}
        };

        var authors2 = new List<AuthorsAccepted1>() {
            new AuthorsAccepted1(){ id = 1, Name="jack"},
            new AuthorsAccepted1(){ id = 2, Name="tim"},
            new AuthorsAccepted1(){ id = 3, Name="james"},
            new AuthorsAccepted1(){ id = 4, Name="mary"}
        };
        
        

        var newModel1 = new Root1();
        newModel1.FullName = fullName;
        newModel1.AuthorsAccepted = authors1;

        var newModel2 = new Root1();
        newModel2.FullName = fullName2;
        newModel2.AuthorsAccepted = authors2;

    }
}

public class Root1
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public List<AuthorsAccepted1> AuthorsAccepted { get; set; }
}
public class AuthorsAccepted1
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class Viewmodel
{
    public Root1 AllModel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There is no third model in your code example. However, `List<T>` offers an `AddRange` method, which you can use to copy the items of one List<AuthorsAccepted1> instance into another List<AuthorsAccepted1> instance...

Comment: that does not work.  this is  how i want the result to look like newModel1
AuthorsAccepted count=4
FullName = Jack

AuthorsAccepted count=4
FullName = Time Dean